# How can I change the text of a button in another screen when I am in a popup-window?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to change the label of the button "Choose Activity" to "Schlafen" (in the Screen "DayWindow"), if the user clicks on the button "Schlafen" in the popup window.
My problem is that I dont know how to access the Screen **"DayWindow"** from the `Popup-Class`.
As you can see in the code, I tried to access it through the `ScreenManager` but than I get the `Error: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

In another try I got the `Error: Screen "day" does not exist`

I would be very thankful for any help and tips.

My Pyhton File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from datetime import date, timedelta
import json  

class MenuWindow(Screen):
    pass

class DayWindow(Screen):
    null = ObjectProperty("Null")

    def btn(self,index):
        show_ActivityPopup()

    def change_button():
        scn = ScreenManager()
        scn.ids.null.text = "Geschafft"

class WeekWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MonthWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
    

class ActivityPopup(FloatLayout):
    def change_text(self):
        DayWindow.change_button()

def show_ActivityPopup():
    show = ActivityPopup()
    ActivityPopupWindow = Popup(title="Activities", content=show, auto_dismiss=False)
    ActivityPopupWindow.open()

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()enter code here
```

My .kv - File

```
WindowManager:
MenuWindow:
DayWindow:
WeekWindow:
MonthWindow:

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "menu"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Time/MoodTracker"
        
        Button:
            text: "Day"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "day"
                root.manager.transition.direction ="left"
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
        
            Button:
                text: "Weelky Overview"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "week"
                    root.manager.transition.direction ="left"
            
            Button:
                text: "Monthly Overview"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "month"
                    root.manager.transition.direction ="left"


<DayWindow>:
    name: "day"
    ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "0:00 - 0:30"
        Button:
            id: null
            text: root.null
            on_release: 
                root.btn(0)
        Label:
            text: "0:30 - 1:00"
            id: Eins
        Button:
            text: "Choose Aviticity"
            on_release: root.btn(1)
        
        Label:
            text: "1:00 - 1:30"

        Button:
            text: "Choose Aviticity"
            on_release: root.btn(2)

        Label:
            text: "1:30 - 2:00"

        Button:
            text: "Choose Aviticity"
            on_release: root.btn(3)
        
        Label:
            text: "2:00 - 2:30"

        Button:
            text: "Choose Aviticity"
            on_release: root.btn(4)

<ActivityPopup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:1
            height: dp(600)
            spacing: "10dp"

            Button:
                text: "Schlafen"
                on_release: 
                    root.change_text()
                    root.parent.parent.parent.dismiss()            
            Button:
                text: "Frühstücken"
                on_release: 
                    root.parent.parent.parent.dismiss()
            
            Button:
                text: "Kochen"

            
            Button:
                text: "Lernen"
            
            Button:
                text: "Joggen"


<WeekWindow>:
    name: "week"

    Button:
        text: "Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "menu"
            root.manager.transition.direction ="right"


<MonthWindow>:
    name: "month"

    Button:
        text: "Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "menu"
            root.manager.transition.direction ="right"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems:
The code:

```
def change_button():
    scn = ScreenManager()
    scn.ids.null.text = "Geschafft"
```

is creating a new instance of `ScreenManager`, which has nothing to do with your `App`. So nothing that you do with `scn` will have any effect on your `App`.

And, in that same method, you are trying to access `ids` of the `ScreenManager`. Even if you were actually dealing with the `WindowManager` in your `App`, this would not work, because the `WindowsManager` has no defined `ids`.

The `ids` defined in your `kv` file are defined in the object that is the root of the rule where that `id` is defined. So, for example, the `null` `id` is defined in the `ids` of the `DayWindow`. The kivy documentation on this issue is confusing due to its multiple uses of the term `root widget`.

The fix is to just modify the `change_text()` method of the `ActivityPopup` class. Here is an updated version of that method, that should fix your problems:

```
class ActivityPopup(FloatLayout):
    def change_text(self):
        scn = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('day')
        scn.ids.null.text = "Geschafft"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Do you know an example where it is useful to create an new instance of 'ScreenManager'?

Comment: And a understanding question:
In a other Window I achieved to change the text of a button with the command: "self.ids.date_minus_label.text = date_minus_str" whereby this is in a function in the "DayWindow"-Class and works just fine. It make sense to me because I have the Screen open in the application where I want to change the text. If I print "self", I get <Screen name='day'>. Why am I not able to change "self" to "DayWindow"?
If I do this I get the error: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'date_minus_label'.

Comment: Because `DayWindow` is a class. You can think of it as the directions on how to build an instance of `DayWindow`. The `self` variable refers to an actual instance of a built `DayWindow`. Please review the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).